# boost/asio: Very simple chat server can't access the messages that are recieved

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, boost, boost-asio

I am learning about boost and was messing around with its server and client communication to make a simple chat server, where anything that a client sends, is just displayed on the server. The server itself doesn't send anything and starts the receiving part. It is pretty straight-forward.

Server code:

```
#include <boost\asio\placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost\bind.hpp>
#include <boost\asio\ip\tcp.hpp>
#include <boost\asio\io_context.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Server
{
private :
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket server_socket;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint server_endpoint;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    std::string msg;

public :
    Server(boost::asio::io_context &io) :
    server_socket(io),
    server_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1"), 27015),
    acceptor(io, server_endpoint)
    {
        acceptor.async_accept(server_socket,
            boost::bind(&Server::async_acceptor_handler, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void async_acceptor_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::cout << "One client connected...\n";

            server_socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(msg),
                boost::bind(&Server::async_read_some_handler, this, 
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "async_acceptor failed with error code : " << ec.value() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Error description : " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void async_read_some_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::cout << msg << std::endl;

            server_socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(msg),
                boost::bind(&Server::async_read_some_handler, this, 
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "async_acceptor failed with error code : " << ec.value() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Error description : " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    Server s(io);

    io.run();
    return 0;
}
```

In the client part, it is again a pretty straight-forward code, simply connects to the server and starts taking input from user and sends to server.

Client code:

```
#include <boost\asio\placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost\bind.hpp>
#include <boost\asio\ip\tcp.hpp>
#include <boost\asio\io_context.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Client
{
private :
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket client_socket;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint server_endpoint;
    std::string msg;

public :
    Client(boost::asio::io_context &iocontext) :
        client_socket(iocontext),
        server_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1"), 27015)
    {
        //connect to server endpoint
        client_socket.async_connect(server_endpoint, 
            boost::bind(&Client::async_connect_handler, this, 
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void async_connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::cout << "Connected to chat server...\n";

            //wait for user input
            std::cin >> msg;
            std::cout << "\rC : " << msg << std::endl;

            client_socket.async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(msg),
                boost::bind(&Client::async_write_some_handler, this, 
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "async_connect failed with error code : " << ec.value() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Error description : " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void async_write_some_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec)
    {
        //wait for user input
        std::cin >> msg;
        std::cout << "\rC : " << msg << std::endl;

        client_socket.async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(msg),
            boost::bind(&Client::async_write_some_handler, this, 
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    Client c(io);

    io.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Now the **problem**:

It works fine, and connects to the server too. I get the proper "Connected to chat server..." in client and "One client connected..." in server. The problem arises after that :

1. In the server console, after the "One client" message, it just starts printing nothing and goes on and on.
2. The messages sent by the client are never showed in the server console.

Problem 1 can be a issue on my part as I am yet to check the wait functions and other calls which make the server wait. If you can guide me on that, it will be more than amazing. But the **major problem** is the **part 2 of the problem**, since, I have no idea why the server is always receiving nothing from client.

PS: This is an incomplete code and I plan to play a bit more with it, so, if there are some major flaws, please tell me so... :)

PPS: Before you say check other questions similar to this, I went through all the similar questions. For ex: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474820/c-boost-asio-networking-server-client) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353940/boost-asio-server-doesnt-receive-message), but this are not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the size of `string msg` in the server side? **It is 0**. So the server reads always 0 bytes.
When you want to read to string and you call `buffer::asio::buffer` string must have some size, for example 10. It means you want to read 10 bytes into `msg`. You can call `msg.resize(10)` (before reading operation is initiated), then some data will be read into `msg` by `async_read_some` (it could be 1,2 bytes, whatever - it is how `async_read_some` works, but the maximum read characters is 10). But it is poor solution.

You are sending text, so you may consider using read data into `streambuf` instead of `string`, when you don't know how many bytes can come from the client side. Then you can call [async_read_until](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until.html) with delimiter - it can be for example new line character.

Another solution is to use [dynamic buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/dynamic_buffer.html). Where data is appened into string and you don't care about the initial size of string buffer. But dynamic buffer doesn't work with member functions of socket like `async_read_some`, it could be used with `async_read` as free function.

Comment: Dude, this is the as perfect as an answer could be, thanks a lot man... :).. I just checked out the string documentation, it actually constructs a string with zero bytes... :O